# Como ver no desktop a versão móvel desse site que não é responsivo?

Tags: mobile, navegador-de-internet, extensão, user-agent

Preciso de acesso à versão móvel dos artigos de um certo site no desktop, para o desenvolvimento de uma extensão.

[Uma página de exemplo](http://www.cracked.com/blog/5-totally-well-meaning-things-people-do-to-ruin-holidays/).

O site não é responsivo, não usa um subdomínio específico para celular, mas mudar o *user-agent* para o de um celular também não resolve. Alguém sabe o que está havendo?

Comment: +1 porque a pergunta gerou um assunto interessante ao desenvolvimento e estudo sobre o assunto principal (mobiles), pois os alguns navegadores hoje são mais do que "simplesmente navegadores", são ferramentas de desenvolvimento com recursos avançados. Ou seja este é um "caso de ferramenta comum entre desenvolvedores" que presumo ser dentro do escopo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - claro que pode até ser fechada pra evitar respostas como links para extensões ou coisas do gênero, mas ainda sim merecia uma resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é necessário *extensões* ou *plugins*, navegadores baseados no Chromium possuem ferramentas avançadas pra simular dispositivos como smartphones e tablets.

### Simular navegadores mobile

Navegue até o site de interesse e usando o Google Chrome aperte:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Ou no Opera:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

Irá aparecer as ferramentas de desenvolvedor:

<kbd>[image: Developer tools]</kbd>

Então clique no icone que parece um celular:

[image: device mode]

Ao clicar irá aparecer esta tela e ele irá entrar em modo de seleção e simulação de dispositivos (no meu caso o padrão está Iphone4):

[image: developer tools chrome e opera]

Depois clique no combo e troque pro modelo de celular desejado:

[image: developer tools chrome e opera]

Observe que existe uma tarja laranja e que o *User-agent* muda (aonde está escrito *UA*), esta mensagem diz que alguns sites é necessário recarregar a página:

[image: developer tools chrome e opera]

Sendo um site não responsivo será necessário recarregar a página com <kbd>F5</kbd> e dependendo se houver cache use o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (que irá ignorar o cache pra aba especifica), veja como ficou o site `pt.stackoverflow.com` depois do <kbd>F5</kbd>:

[image: developer tools chrome e opera]

Existem alguns sites que usam Cookies ou [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) pra salvar a página padrão que deve usar, mobile ou desktop, então nem o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> irá funcionar, neste caso siga estes passos:

1. Abra uma janela anonima (não abra nenhum site nela)
2. Clique <kbd>F12</kbd> se Chrome ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> se for Opera
3. Então selecione o `Device` desejado
4. A seguir cole na barra de endereços o site desejado.

Veja como ficou no modo anonimo:

[image: Modo anonimo]

### Funções extras das ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chrome e Opera

- Simular conexões mais lentas:

  [image: developer tools chrome e opera network]
- o *Potrait* troca a largura pela altura e vice-versa, ou seja simula a rotação e o ícone com o 2 ao troca o *pixel ratio* que simula telas com retina.

  [image: developer tools chrome e opera]

Comment: Muito obrigado, Guilherme! Nunca imaginei que pudesse ser algum cookie. A vida toda o user-agent funcionou pra mim. Agora posso prosseguir com meu trabalho aqui. Além de ter resolvido o problema pra mim, ficou muito completa a resposta. Eu daria dois upvotes, rsrs.